Google Chat API: 404 Error When Using Existing Thread Key with Webhook
I’m currently working with the Google Chat API to send messages to specific spaces using webhooks. I have encountered a persistent 404 error (Requested entity was not found) when trying to send a message using a particular thread key, even though this thread key has been working in other spaces.
Here are some details about my implementation:

I use the following URL to send messages:
https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/SPACE_NAME/messages?key=YOUR_API_KEY&token=YOUR_TOKEN&messageReplyOption=REPLY_MESSAGE_FALLBACK_TO_NEW_THREAD and body is { "text": "Hello!", "thread": { "threadKey": "threadName" } }
I have confirmed that the thread key exists and has not been deleted or modified because the previous messages are still available in that particular thread. However, I get a 404 error when sending to this specific thread key.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Changing the Webhook URL: I created a new webhook URL and updated it, but the error persisted.
Using Different Thread Keys: When I change the thread key, the message goes through successfully. However, I cannot change the thread key for approximately 80 other spaces that depend on the same thread key.
Checking Permissions: I have verified that the bot has the necessary permissions in the space settings, but I still encounter issues.

Given that changing the thread key resolves the issue, but I cannot do this for all spaces, I'm seeking insights into the following:

What could cause a specific thread key to become invalid or return a 404 error?
Are there settings or limitations in Google Chat that could impact the usability of thread keys in certain spaces?
Does the messageReplyOption influence the thread handling in a way that might lead to this error?

Any guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Maybe you can try removing this part
messageReplyOption=REPLY_MESSAGE_FALLBACK_TO_NEW_THREAD

Yes, after removing this, we are able to send the message, but every time it creates a new thread instead of replying to the existing thread with that threadKey.

/maybe you can try other values for MessageReplyOption

@AmanKumarRana Any chance you ever resolved this?

@MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst We implemented a mechanism where, if we receive a status code of 404, we append a numeric value to the thread key (e.g., '-some numeric value'), creating a new thread. After that, all subsequent messages fall back into the same thread.
                    retryCount++;
                    threadKey = threadKey + "-" + retryCount;
                    webhookURL = webhook + threadKey;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while (retryCount < maxRetry);```
